# Operate X clipboard from command line

Tags: command-line, x11, clipboard

I'd like to copy and paste to the clipboard from the command line.

I've found two utilities that works with "mouse" selection: `xclip` and `xsel`. But they both ignore the clipboard that is filled with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> in GUI applications. So I may not paste things that were copied in this way.

What command line utility works like `xclip` or `xsel` but is compatible with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>?

Comment: It looks like `xclip` and `xsel` accept an option `-selection clipboard` to use a non-default X selection. Did you try that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`xclip` uses the clipboard if you specify `-selection clipboard`:

```
xclip -selection clipboard -o
```

prints the contents of the clipboard (as filled with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> in a GUI application).

The equivalent option for `xsel` is `-b` (or `--clipboard`).

Comment: xclip works perfectly. But I'm confused. I've already tried -selection clipboard and get no result. There are conditions under which it doesn't work, but I'm failed to reproduce this conditions

Comment: The X selection/clipboard has a few weird edge cases; see http://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html for an overview (and http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/ if you want all the details).

Comment: You can use `-se c` instead of the long `-selection clipboard`, too.

Comment: Some times xclip not works: when i copy text in firefox, then switch to linux console, and run `DISPLAY=:0 xclip -selection clipboard -o`, it block forever. This problem will gone after i restart firefox.